# Import csv file into MongoDB with arrays from a column

Tags: mongodb, import, nosql

I have an Excel file that I converted to a csv and imported into my running MongoDB storage, but there was trouble with one column of the data from the csv file. One column, called Room, occasionally, but not always, contains values separated by a comma (ex. "101, 103").

Running:

`$ mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline`

gave no errors, but for documents that are supposed to have 2 values for Room, there was just one. For example "101, 102" became "101," in the db.

Is there an option for `mongoimport` that allows me to specify an array for a certain column?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Import the data from `CSV` as

```
$ mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline
```

After that , you just have to use

```
db.things.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {   el.Room = el.Room.split(',');   db.things.save(el); });
```

So, It will solve your problem.